# Java Google Calendar API: Send email notification when creating event

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using java google calendar API. Whenever I create a new event **I would like to send an email notification to all attendees**.

*I guess/expect there are 2 ways how to achieve that:*

1. Set it as the calendar property
2. Set it ad hoc as property on the created event

I don't care which of these options I use but I don't know how to do it programmatically and **I am struggling to find any example of the code.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it), about the `sendUpdates` parameter:

> Whether to send notifications about the creation of the new event.
>   Note that some emails might still be sent. The default is false.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - "all": Notifications are sent to all guests.
> - "externalOnly": Notifications are sent to non-Google Calendar guests
>     only.
> - "none": No notifications are sent. This value should only be
>     used for migration use cases (note that in most migration cases the
>     import method should be used).

You can follow the [insert Example](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples) besides the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java) to set the previous configuration, but take into account  that **there is an outdated dependency** that makes you use the deprecated `sendNotifications` instead of `sendUpdates`:

---

`compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev305-1.23.0'`

should be

`compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev401-1.25.0'`

---

I already reported the issue to Google.

Assuming that you already have the object created event, with the list of attendees, the API call should be:

`service.events().insert(calendarId, event).setSendUpdates("all").execute();`